# Angular Tour of Heroes: Why is one assigned with colon and another by equal signs

Tags: angular, typescript

**Environment: Angular 5+**
Source: https://angular.io/tutorial

In the `heroes.component.ts` class there is an assignment with a colon like this:

```js
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];
```

But then in the `app.component.ts` class there is an assignment with equal sign:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
}
```

Why is this baffling me?

Comment: The colon doesn't assign anything other than a type; `heroes` is still undefined. The equal assigns a value, and the type is implied; string in this instance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this code `heroes: Hero[];` nothing is being assigned to the var `heroes`, but you're stating that it is an array of `Hero` (for now it is `undefined`).

Now, in this code `title = 'app';` you're are assigning the string `'app'` to the var `title`, since the typescript compiler can infer that `'app'` is a string there is no need to specify it (`title: string = 'app';`), not being this way in the case of `heroes`, which the compiler doesn't know what will be assigned to the var unless you specify it by "telling" `: Hero[]` (it is an array of `Hero`)

Comment: It should be `undefined` until a value is given to it

Answer (score 3):

The first sample indicates that `heroes` is an array of `Hero` objects; but does not actually give the property a value.

The second sample assigns the `title` property the string `app` but does not say what type it is. Because you assigned a string; it is typed as a string.

You should almost always declare what type a variable is; as you won't always get implicit types and can end up with `any` variables. Initializing is also good practice; if you don't initialize, just understand that it holds an `undefined` value until you do assign to the variable/property.

Answer (score 2):

As @Richards explained in the comments:

You are developing using the Typescript language, it adds many types on top of JavaScript to help you code and debug.

`heroes: Hero[];` means that `heroes` is an array of type `Hero`. Nothing is assigned, `heroes` is currently `undefined`

`title = 'app';` means that `title` is variable with an assigned value of `'app'` which is of type `string`

You can only assign values with the `=` operator.